# Edit data directly in table field

Tags: jquery

I have the below PHP that outputs an HTML table where each row contains a password input. The point of the table is to allow a user to edit these passwords. On each password input element, there is an attribute named "pattern" where I store a regular expression. I would like to force the user to enter a password that matches this regular expression and show an error message if the password is not validated.

How can I achieve this?

**My PHP/HTML:**

```
<?php 
$result = mysqli_query( $conn, "select id, password from user");
$num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result); 
?>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th style="cursor:pointer">
            Password
        </th>
    </tr>
    <?php
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($resa))
{
    ?><tr class="edit_tr" title="click to edit">
        <td class="edit_td" id="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">
            <span id="password_<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" ></span>
            <input type="password" value="<?php echo $row['password']; ?>" data-pattern="(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{8,}"  class="editbox" id="password_input_<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**My JavaScript:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".edit_td").click(function() {
        document.getElementById('user_insert').style.display = "none";

        var ID = $(this).attr('id');
        $("#password_" + ID).hide();
        $("#password_input_" + ID).show();

        {

          var ID = $(this).attr('id');
          var first = $("#password_input_" + ID).val();
          var dataString = 'id=' + ID + '&password=' + first
          if (first.length > {
              if (confirm('Are you sure to modify the password ?')) {
                $.ajax({

                  type: "POST",
                  url: "modify_password.php",
                  data: dataString,
                  cache: false,
                  success: function(html) {

                    $("#password_" + ID).html(first);
                  }
                });
              }
            } else {
              alert('don't let empty.');
              }

            });

          // Edit input box click action
          $(".editbox").mouseup(function() {
            return false
          });


          $(document).mouseup(function() {
            $(".editbox").hide();
            $(".text").show();

          });

        });
```

Comment: soallow the function flow, but diregard the password field?

Comment: why do you vote me down. my function works. Only the patten is not working

Comment: I didn't down vote you? I was just asking if that is what you meant.

Comment: The downvotes are likely because you have not clearly stated what your code is supposed to do nor how it fails to achieve the desired results. As a result, its not clear what you are asking, and it doesnt help that your code is not formatted at all

Comment: what i mean is to prevent  editing  if user does not respect the pattern

Comment: i'm sorry if i'm not clear enough. I would like to prevent edit it pattern is not respected. For now edit can be done even if pattern is not respected.

Comment: Oh, i see. The reg expression is not valid, then undo to original state.

Comment: I'll make a fiddle right now..

Answer (score 1):

You have several syntax errors that would be obvious if your code was formatted correctly. Putting that aside, you'll need to get the pattern from the element's `pattern` attribute and create a regular expression with it then use that to attempt to match the user input.

This would work:

Change the PHP line to `<input type="password" value="<?php echo $row['password']; ?>" original-password="<?php echo $row['password']; ?>" pattern="(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{8,}"  class="editbox" id="password_input_<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"/>`

#### [Working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DelightedDoD/apm61vgf/1/)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.edit_td').click(function() {
    var ID = $(this).attr('id');
    var $pswdInput = $('#password_input_' + ID);
    var $pswdSpan = $('#password_' + ID);
    $('#user_insert').hide();
    $pswdSpan.hide();
    $pswdInput.show();
    var ID = $(this).attr('id');
    var first = $pswdInput.val();
    var dataString = 'id=' + ID + '&password=' + first
    var regex = new RegExp($pswdInput.attr('pattern'));
    if (first.match(regex)) {
      if (confirm('Are you sure you want to modify the password ?')) {
        $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: 'modify_password.php',
          data: dataString,
          cache: false,
          success: function(html) {
            $pswdSpan.html(first);
          }
        });
      }
      else $pswdInput.val($pswdInput.attr('original-password')); // reset original password
    } 
    else {
      $pswdInput.val($pswdInput.attr('original-password'));
      alert('Invalid password provided'); // reset original password
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="password_1"></span>
<input type="password" value="somePassword1" original-password="somePassword1" pattern="(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{8,}" class="editbox" id="password_input_1" />


<button class="edit_td" id="1">Edit password </button>
```

**Also, I would suggest that you either update your regex to disallow characters that will break your datastring, or encode/decode the input**.

For example `somePas&sword1` will validate with your current regex but the `&` will break your ajax call. Youll need to disallow all chars that have meaning in URLs or use `var first = encodeURIComponent($pswdInput.val());` then decode it on the server to avoid issues (better choice IMHO)

### Make sure that you also validate the password on the server as this method alone is not sufficient as the user could easily manipulate this on the client side, this should be for UX purposes only

Comment: @branche Happy to help, dont forget to close the question if it's fixed now :)

Comment: im sorry i don' know how to close cause im new

Comment: something need to check when the new password entered is incorrected the previous one should be kept..

Comment: @branche to close a question, click the check mark next to the answer that helped. Regarding the downvotes, I have re-worded the question to be more clear and you can see how that helps :) , Regarding setting the input back to the original password, see my update above.....though I dont really see the point since the passwords will all be hidden and just show dots anyway, there really isnt any reason to have the original passwords rendered on the page at all honestly

Answer (score -1):

This is just basic change added to your current code. Though it seems some of the syntax was off with brackerts and stuff.

```
 $(document).ready(function()
 {

 $(".edit_td").click(function()
 {
   var $this = ($this); //store current object
   var priorPassword = $(this).val();//so you cna use later

   document.getElementById('user_insert').style.display="none";
  var ID=$(this).attr('id');
  $("#password_"+ID).hide();
  $("#password_input_"+ID).show();

  var ID=$(this).attr('id');
  var first=$("#password_input_"+ID).val();
  var dataString = 'id='+ ID +'&password='+first

  if(first.length > 0)
  {
    if(confirm('Are you sure to modify the password ?')) {
    //validate password here.    

    $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: "modify_password.php",
         data: dataString,
        cache: false,
        success: function(html)
        {
          $("#password_"+ID).html(first);
        }
    });
 }
 else
 {
    alert('don't let empty.');
  $(this).val(priorPassword);//sets it back to prior password
 }
});

  // Edit input box click action
 $(".editbox").mouseup(function()
   {
  return false
  });


  $(document).mouseup(function()
  {
 $(".editbox").hide();
  $(".text").show();

  });

  });
```

Comment: a fiddle would work better !, it's bit hard for me to see

Comment: I just realised though that it relies on the php file externally. Just add the two variables I added, and insert the change only under the alert telling them password incorrect.

Comment: did your code work before, except your validation, or did none of it work?

Comment: Cause alot of your brackets seemed off.